# How to connect a microcontroller to a gps module and receive position

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a small project using IoT.
This project consist of a bus stop with microcontroller(Open source) and a display.
Also, a microcontroller(Open source) with a GPS module as a bus.

This is our code that we modified from toptechboy

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from Adafruit_IO import Client, Feed, RequestError
ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY ='*********'
ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME ='********'
aio = Client(ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME, ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY)
digital = aio.feeds('eproject')
GPIO.setup("P8_8", GPIO.OUT)
UART.setup("UART1")
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyO1',9600)
class GPS:
        def __init__(self):
                UPDATE_10_sec=  "$PMTK220,10000*2F\r\n" #Update Every 10 Seconds
                UPDATE_5_sec=  "$PMTK220,5000*1B\r\n"   #Update Every 5 Seconds$
                UPDATE_1_sec=  "$PMTK220,1000*1F\r\n"   #Update Every One Second
                UPDATE_200_msec=  "$PMTK220,200*2C\r\n" #Update Every 200 Milli$
                #This set is used to set the rate the GPS takes measurements
                MEAS_10_sec = "$PMTK300,10000,0,0,0,0*2C\r\n" #Measure every 10$
                MEAS_5_sec = "$PMTK300,5000,0,0,0,0*18\r\n"   #Measure every 5 $
                MEAS_1_sec = "$PMTK300,1000,0,0,0,0*1C\r\n"   #Measure once a s$
                MEAS_200_msec= "$PMTK300,200,0,0,0,0*2F\r\n"  #Meaure 5 times a$
                #Set the Baud Rate of GPS
                BAUD_57600 = "$PMTK251,57600*2C\r\n"          #Set Baud Rate at$
                BAUD_9600 ="$PMTK251,9600*17\r\n"             #Set 9600 Baud Ra$
                #Commands for which NMEA Sentences are sent
                ser.write(BAUD_57600)
                time.sleep(1)
                ser.baudrate=57600
                GPRMC_ONLY= "$PMTK314,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0*29\$
                GPRMC_GPGGA="$PMTK314,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0*28\$
                SEND_ALL ="$PMTK314,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0*28\r\$
                SEND_NOTHING="$PMTK314,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0*28$
                ser.write(UPDATE_200_msec)
                time.sleep(1)
                ser.write(MEAS_200_msec)
                time.sleep(1)
                ser.write(GPRMC_GPGGA)
                time.sleep(1)
                ser.flushInput()
                ser.flushInput()
                print ("GPS Initialized")
        def read(self):
                ser.flushInput()
                ser.flushInput()
                while ser.inWaiting()==0:
                        pass
                self.NMEA1=ser.readline()
                while ser.inWaiting()==0:
                        pass
                self.NMEA2=ser.readline()
                NMEA1_array=self.NMEA1.split(',')
                NMEA2_array=self.NMEA2.split(',')
                if NMEA1_array[0]=='$GPRMC':
                        self.timeUTC=NMEA1_array[1][:-8]+':'+NMEA1_array[1][-8:$
                        self.latDeg=NMEA1_array[3][:-7]
                        self.latMin=NMEA1_array[3][-7:]
                        self.latHem=NMEA1_array[4]
                        self.lonDeg=NMEA1_array[5][:-7]
                        self.lonMin=NMEA1_array[5][-7:]
                        self.lonHem=NMEA1_array[6]
                        self.knots=NMEA1_array[7]
                if NMEA1_array[0]=='$GPGGA':
                        self.fix=NMEA1_array[6]
                        self.altitude=NMEA1_array[9]
                        self.sats=NMEA1_array[7]
                if NMEA2_array[0]=='$GPRMC':
                        self.timeUTC=NMEA2_array[1][:-8]+':'+NMEA1_array[1][-8:$
                        self.latDeg=NMEA2_array[3][:-7]
                        self.latMin=NMEA2_array[3][-7:]
                        self.latHem=NMEA2_array[4]
                        self.lonDeg=NMEA2_array[5][:-7]
                        self.lonMin=NMEA2_array[5][-7:]
                        self.lonHem=NMEA2_array[6]
                        self.knots=NMEA2_array[7]
             if NMEA2_array[0]=='$GPGGA':
                        self.fix=NMEA2_array[6]
                        self.altitude=NMEA2_array[9]
                        self.sats=NMEA2_array[7]
            myGPS=GPS()

            while True:

         data = aio.receive(digital.key)
         myGPS.read()
         print (m print (myGPS.NMEA2)

         if int(data.value) == 1:
            print('received ON \n')
            GPIO.output("P8_8", GPIO.HIGH)

         if myGPS.fix!=0:
             print ('Universal Time: ',myGPS.timeUTC)
             print ('You are Tracking: ',myGPS.sats,' satellites')
             print ('My Latitude: ',myGPS.latDeg, 'Degrees ', myGPS.latMin,' minutes ', myGPS.latHem)
             print ('My Longitude: ',myGPS.lonDeg, 'Degrees ', myGPS.lonMin,' minutes ', myGPS.lonHem)
             print ('My Speed: ', myGPS.knots)
             print ('My Altitude: ',myGPS.altitude)
         elif int(data.value) == 0:
             print('received OFF \n')
             GPIO.output("P8_8", GPIO.LOW)
```

And this is the code error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m.py", line 83, in <module>
    myGPS=GPS()
  File "m.py", line 29, in __init__
    ser.write(BAUD_57600)
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 532, in write
    d = to_bytes(data)
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 63, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '$PMTK251,57600*2C\r\n'
```

I want microcontroller1 to act as a gps and create variables that i will send them to microcontroller2, so microcontroller2 will display a live map of where the bus is going.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run code written for Python 2.x on Python 3.x.

As you might know, one of the key differences between those is that Python 3.x uses Unicode for strings (for more details see [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/strings-unicode-and-bytes-in-python-3-everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-27dc02ff2686)).

You have two choices: run with Python 2.x or port the code. If you go for the second the only change (at first sight, you might need other minor things) is to encode your commands before writing them on the port, for instance, use:

```
ser.write(BAUD_57600.encode())
```

instead of your `ser.write(BAUD_57600)`